# How to add liquidity to syncswap using JavaScript and ethers.js?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I tried to add liquidity to syncswap using ethers.js
This is my code.

```
const zksync = require("zksync-web3");
const ethers = require('ethers');
const zkSyncProvider = new zksync.Provider("https://testnet.era.zksync.dev");
const ethProvider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("goerli");
async function main() {
  const wETHAddress = "0x20b28B1e4665FFf290650586ad76E977EAb90c5D";
  const usdcAddress = "0x0faF6df7054946141266420b43783387A78d82A9";
  const routerAddress = "0xB3b7fCbb8Db37bC6f572634299A58f51622A847e";
  const classicPoolFactoryAddress = "0xf2FD2bc2fBC12842aAb6FbB8b1159a6a83E72006";
  const classicPoolFactoryAbi = require("./abi/SyncSwap/SyncSwapClassicPoolFactoryABI.json");
  const routerAbi = require("./abi/SyncSwap/SyncSwapRouterABI.json");
  const signer = new zksync.Wallet("private key", zkSyncProvider, ethProvider) // The factory of the Classic Pool.
  const classicPoolFactory = new zksync.Contract(classicPoolFactoryAddress, classicPoolFactoryAbi, zkSyncProvider); // Gets the address of the ETH/USDC Classic Pool. 
  // wETH is used internally by the pools. 
  const poolAddress = await classicPoolFactory.getPool(wETHAddress, usdcAddress);
  // Checks whether the pool exists. 
  if (poolAddress === ethers.constants.AddressZero) {
    console.log('pool not exists') return
  }
  const router = new zksync.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, signer);
  const tokenInputs = [{
    token: wETHAddress,
    amount: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
  }, {
    token: usdcAddress,
    amount: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
  }];
  const response = await router.addLiquidity(poolAddress, tokenInputs, [], 0, ethers.constants.AddressZero, [], );
  console.log(response);
}
main();
```

But it returns following error.

> cannot estimate gas

What's wrong?

https://github.com/syncswap/core-contracts/issues/2

Comment: In the future, please format your code so that it is readable instead of making others do it for you. Also, you are asking a lot of the volunteers who answer questions here by basically dumping code and asking us to debug it for you. We'd much rather see your attempts to debug it yourself and what you've found.